# how to show drupal message “field is required” from webform validation in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform, formvalidation-plugin, drupal-form-validation

So when a webform is validated it does not sends the drupal message "X field is required", it creates only the red border around the field.
how would I show the Drupal messages from triggering during validation? it is a block view of webform in drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use webform validation you can use

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation module you can add validation for you field you want